# Assign certificate to backend HTTP settings in Azure Application GW

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How can I attach a certificate for the backend HTTP setting via DevOps Repo. The certificate is in my PC. Not much familiar with this coding logic.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

> How can I attach a certificate for the backend HTTP setting via DevOps Repo. The certificate is in my PC

To achieve this, you could submit your certificate to the Secure files in the Azure Devops Library:

[image]

[**Secure files**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops):

> Use the Secure Files library to store files such as signing
> certificates, Apple Provisioning Profiles, Android Keystore files, and
> SSH keys on the server without having to commit them to your source
> repository. Secure files are defined and managed in the Library tab in
> Azure Pipelines.

Then we could use the [Download Secure File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) task in a pipeline to download a secure file to the agent machine.

Next, we could use powershell scripts to attach a certificate for the backend HTTP:

[Configure end to end TLS by using Application Gateway with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell#create-an-application-gateway-configuration-object)